# Obtaining lines from an array and stopping at a particular character

Tags: perl

I'm looking for some assistance on a script which can go through the lines of an array, printing them to the screen and stopping when the script detects a specific character, in this case the `!` mark. I have tried using the `foreach` statement but ain't getting any success...

Example of the Array (`@lines`) contents is:

```
ip vrf test
rd 2856:10000331
export map SetAltMgmtRT
route-target export 2856:10000331
route-target import 2856:10000331
maximum routes 1000 75
!
```

The script I have so far is:

```
elsif ( $action eq "show_vrf" ) {
            my $cmd = "show run | begin <VRF_NAME>";
            $cmd = $cmd . " | i $include" if($include) ;
            my @lines = $s->cmd(String => $cmd,
                            Prompt  => "/$enableprompt/",
                            Timeout => 10);
            foreach $lines (@lines) {
                    <statement, this is where I am stuck>
            }
            print $lines;
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to learn about `next`and `last`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the criteria for stopping? Any exclamation mark or just one on its own line? Or just a line beginning with an exclamation mark?

You've also got several things called `lines` which you need to sort out.

```
my $output;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    last if $line =~ m/^!/; # leave loop if line starts with an exclamation mark
    $output .= $line;
}
print $output;
```

For your additional requirements in your comment below (the data has more than one exclamation mark) you'd need something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @output; # assign output chunks into an array
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ m/^!/) {
        $i++;
        next;
    }
    $output[$i] .= $line;
}
print Dumper(\@output);
```

Answer (score 2):

break if line matches !

```
last if ($line =~ /!/);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(@lines){
last if(/\!$/);# this will be true if there is an Exclamation mark at the end of line
print $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, it was the last if statement that had me caught...appreciate the speedy replies and of course the help.

Comment: The above worked fine allowing me to capture the first instance in the array as per the example above, but is there a way I can search for the same instance again within the same array, using the same method outlined above with stopping at the '!' mark?  The information I wish to pull appears 3 times throughout the array. Thanks.